# firebase refresh Access token upon expire / next request

Tags: google-oauth

Does anyone know if there is a way to reauthicate an access token with the the updated google identity library and/or firebase.

At the moment im utlising the firebase login to authenticate a user and load their information, this is providing back an accesstoken that can then be used with other google api calls. After an hour this token expires as expected, but there does not appear to be a way to re-auth the user and get a new access token without prompting the user to re-sign in.

Have found a few soultions online, but all refer to the legacy sign in documentaion that is no longer avaiable for new sites.

the current work around I have in place is to use the popup but have the prompt set to none with a hint for the user, this appears to work but the popup does still apear which can be a bit misleading.

Thanks